# Aria Live Region Keeps Repeating on Angular 2 ngIf Validation

Tags: angular, accessibility, wai-aria, jaws-screen-reader

I have:

```html
<div aria-live="polite" id="signInIdError" 
  *ngIf="!signInId.valid && (signInId.touched || isSubmitted)"
  class="inline-validation critical">
    <p>{{ "FYPVERROR" | translate }}</p>
</div>
```

The issue is, when the error shows up dynamically on field validation, the error is read non-stop and not just once.

How to make this work? I have tried assigning div role='region' with aria-live="polite" as well as just aria-live="polite" and it doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: Which browser ? Which screen reader ? Do you mean really repeatedly even if you do nothing, or repeatedly but only when you press keys or do something ? Do you have a page where we could test ?

Comment: All browsers, Jaws, repeatedly as soon as there is an inline validation. Unfortuneately cannot provide a page, only the snippet above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had similar issue. I tried implementing  `aria-live` and `ngIf` on different elements and worked for me.

In your case, this code might work:

```
<div id="signInIdError" class="inline-validation critical" 
*ngIf="Condition"> <p aria-live="polite"> Some Text </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I have an idea on the cause, but have no solution yet.

I suspect Angular to do at least one of these three things at each validation cycle:

- Remove the element from the DOM and add it again
- Make the element invisible and visible again
- Clear the text of the element and fill it it again

Making an aria-live region visible, adding a new one in the DOM or updating its contents all trigger the accessibility API of the browser/OS and so cause Jaws to read again the contents. There is no other reason why Jaws would suddenly become crazy and repeatedly read the contents if none of these events occurrs.

Against the later one, you might use the aria-relavant attribute, but Jaws doesn't support it very well. Anyway, knowing the nature of ngIf, Angular does probably the first one, and you can't prevent Jaws from reading a newly appeared live region (whether it has been added in the DOM or made visible via CSS display), as it would be against the base principle of live regions.

You may try the hidden attribute or the CSS display property instead of using ngIf, but by my reasonning above, I doubt that it will work better.

So, the next questions are:

- How to verify if my reasonning is indeed correct / what Angular does really do ?
- If I correctly guessed what Angular does, how we could prevent it from aggressively updating the element so often when it shouldn't ?

I haven't yet enough Angular 2 experience to answer these two questions. I will update this answer if I have any news.

Comment: I think you are right, it's silly -- thought it would be as simple as adding the live region,